# stop all events under an overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an overlay div which covers a container div  displaying the results. 
But when I click on the overlay it has to disappear.

So, I tried setting `pointer-events: none;` on the overlay div. 
But my issue is the click event on the overlay doesn't work now.

What is the best way to implement this?

```
<div class="overlay container" id="main-div">
  <div id="results-div">
  #Image results are shown and have some events binded to it.
  </div>
</div>


$("#main-div").click(function(){
 #Some events related to it    
});
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: really not clear what behavior you want. Perhaps explanation of overlay purpose would help. A demo in jsfiddle.net would definitely be useful

Comment: If i understood you correctly you want to add event handler on `.container` to toggle class `.overlay'? with css `.overlay * { pointer-events: none; }`  ?

Comment: Look at [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/LCEUK/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve what you want with this simple function :

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $('.overlay').click(function () {
     $('#pop').fadeOut();
  })
})
```

But for that you need make a change in your HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="pop">
  <div class="overlay" id="main-div"></div>
  <div id="results-div">
    #Image results are shown and have some events binded to it.
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this demo to see the whole styles **http://jsfiddle.net/USk7U/**

Answer (score 0):

after removing the `pointer-events: none` from your css, will this not work?

```
$('#main-div').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  // do stuff
  $(this).hide();
});
```

I assume you're trying to hide the `#main-div` when you click anywhere, right?

Also, are you sure you're binding the event *after* the dom element is showing?  If not, you might try [jQuery's `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('click', '#main-div', function(ev) { ... } );
```

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to hide it but trying to remove the class overlay from it. But as it has pointer-events:none events on it also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#main-div").click(function(event){
  if($(event.target).is(".overlay")){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("overlay")
  }else{
    $(this).addClass("overlay");
  }
});
```

if target has overlay class then remove it,or else just add it.

dont add/remove pointer events because dont want to disable click for ever.